# Как в php удалить строки выделенные с помощью chekbox?

Tags: php, sql, веб-программирование, php7

Вывожу таблицу с помощью

```
?><form action = "delete.php" method = "post"><?php 
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $data['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . long2ip ($data['ip_addr']) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $data['namepc'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $data['pass'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $data['passadm'] . '</td>';
    echo "<td width='10px'><input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value=". $data['id'] ."></td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '<input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="Удалить отмеченные" />'; 
?></form><?php
```

Затем создаю delete.php
и пытаюсь то что должно удалять строку в БД отмеченную через checkbox. Вот последнее до чего я догадался

```
    <pre>

<?php 

require_once 'login.php';
$db_server = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);


foreach ($_POST['check'] as $item) 
{
  $query = "DELETE FROM vlc WHERE id=$item" ;
 $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
 echo "$query"; 
}

?>
</pre>
```

Comment: Я там забыл /* */ убрать! Не обращайте внимание

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант:

```
$list = implode(',',$_POST['check']);
$query = "DELETE FROM `vlc` WHERE id IN ($list)";
mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
```

Comment: Не работает почему то , ошибок не каких не показывает ,но и записи не удаляются .

Comment: Подебаж каждую переменную, посмотри какой запрос формирует, еще в логи сервера нужно глянуть, может там будет что-то.

Comment: Слава SQL-инъекциям!

Comment: предложили сделать так
<pre>

<?php 

require_once 'login.php';
$db_server = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);


foreach ($_POST['check'] as $item) 
{
 $query = "DELETE FROM vlc WHERE id=".$item ;
 $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
  echo 'id='.$item.'<br>';
  echo 'query='.$query.'<br>';
  echo 'result='.$result.'<br>'; // или print_r($result);
  echo '---'.'<br>';
}
?>
</pre>

Вывод

id=20
query=DELETE FROM vlc WHERE id=20
result=
---
Я так понимаю нету подключения к БД , тобишь запрос к нему не доходит или что -то в этом духе

Comment: `var_dump($result);`
Если неудача, вернет `False`

Comment: var_dump($result) вернул FALSE. А может быть проблема в том что я использую в обоих php файлах
require_once 'login.php'; ?

Comment: Добавь проверку подключения:
`if (!$db_server) {
        echo "Текст ошибки error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }`

Comment: Использовал echo __DIR__;
Вывел /var/www/test.local
В принципе все верно. в этом test.local лежит и index.php (выводит таблицу) и сам delete.php.

$db_server = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$db_server) { echo "Текст ошибки error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL; exit; }
Ошибок не выдает

Comment: Проблему нашел,в delete.php отсутствовала строка
mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
И тут у меня назревает еще вопрос. Это получается что в каждом php файле который я создам нужно писать

require_once 'login.php';
$db_server = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);

?

Comment: Создай файл с подключением к базе и инклудь его куда нужно